# Installing program (dot) on system search path in R

Tags: r

I'm a social scientist having a hard time struggling through the technical instructions for integrating the graphing program `dot`[documented here](http://www.graphviz.org/Documentation/dotguide.pdf) with the `sem` package [documented here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sem/sem.pdf).

I have successfully run the command `pathDiagram` in the `sem` package, which outputs code that is presumably supposed to be read into `dot.` The documentation for the `sem` package says

```
 "To obtain graphics output directly, the dot program must be on the system search path."
```

I'm sure that this is a totally mundane question, but I'd really appreciate help. I'm lost.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Mac OS-X Mountain Lion

Comment: A couple ideas here. First, if you run the examples in the help page, do you get a graph file?  Second, are you absolutely sure that the graph wasn't created but is "hiding" in some output directory such as the default output directory used by `dot` ?

Comment: It will not produce a diagram at the interactive graphics device, but rather needs a `file=` argument to construct a pdf file (the default).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R execute this command:

```
Sys.which("dot")
```

This will tell you whether a system call will be able to find your 'dot' installation. You did install 'dot', right?

The Graphviz pkg file for MacOS greater than or equal to 10.6 (and your ML is 10.8) can be obtained from AT&T labs: http://www.graphviz.org/Download.php

After installing from its .pkg file (with the same Graphviz version 2.30.1 on OSX 10.6.8) I get:

```
> Sys.which(c("dot"))
                 dot 
"/usr/local/bin/dot"
```

This does NOT open up `dot`. It merely confirms that the dot program can be found on by R. Running the first example on hte `?pathDiagram` page only outputs a source file to the console which could be used for `dot` to the console, because no file argument is given, but if you add a file argument it creates a pdf file using `dot` with a message to the console screen:

```
pathDiagram(sem.dhp, min.rank='RIQ, RSES, RParAsp, FParAsp, FSES, FIQ', file="test",
 max.rank='ROccAsp, REdAsp, FEdAsp, FOccAsp', output.type="graphics", graphics.fmt="pdf")
#Running  dot -Tpdf -o test.pdf  test.dot
```

This produced a file in my working directory that could be viewed with Preview.app.  If you want to use `dot` on its own, you will need to read its manual and follow the instructions for using it in a standalone manner.

Comment: I thought that I did, but the command doesn't seem to be working.  I downloaded the  Grapviz package as a PKG, opened it, and installed it.  Should running the command `pathDiagram` after executing `Sys.which("dot")` open up `dot` automatically if I have installed Graphviz? So sorry to be obtuse :(

Comment: What was the result of `Sys.which('dot')` ? As David said, it will return the path if `dot` is found by `R` .  If a path is returned, then `pathDiagram` will find `dot` .

Answer (score 0):

### Update as per comments:

If when you type `which dot` in terminal, you get a response with a path, then it is safe to say that `graphviz` is installed.

As per `pathDiagram`'s manual  (ie, `?pathDiagram`), it is not intended to return a value.

Instead, use the `file` argument to specify where to save the output to.

```
  pathDiagram(model=SomeModelInR, file="path/to/file", ...)
```

---

*This seems to be more of a general mac os x question, but anyway, here we go:*

In your `applications > utilities` folder, open up terminal.

*(i'm assuming dot is called `dot` if not please modify accordingly)*
Type `which dot`
    -     this will show you the path to dot, perhaps something like `/usr/bin/dot`
    -   in this case, the path you are looking for in the next part is `/usr/bin`

Type `echo $PATH`
  -  this will show you several paths separated by `:`
  -  If the path you got with `which dot` is listed as one of those paths, then you are all set.
  -  If not, please see the link below on how to modify

Also see: 
[How To Edit Your PATH Environment Variables On Mac](http://hathaway.cc/2008/06/how-to-edit-your-path-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x/)

Comment: This may be a bit more complicated because R may have a different path than is in whatever shell this user may be using for Terminal.

Comment: Hi there - Just checking in. I followed these (very helpful!) instructions, and everything seems to be as you've specified.  When I run `pathDiagram` after running `Sys.which("dot"), however, nothing seems to be happening. (R just shows me code).